# Why is it sufficient to consider only the longest path of a tree rooted at A

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand why the problem was solved in certain way.

The problem is to prove that given a graph of tree, pick any two nodes $A$ and $B$, and use those nodes as the root, the height of the tree rooted at $A$ is no more than 2 times the height rooted at $B$ (or $h_A \leq 2*h_B$).

The way the problem was solved was to find a node $L$ such that it has the longest distance from the root of the tree, $A$, and calculate the distance, call it $h_A$.

Then proceed to find the height of the tree rooted at $B$, and call it $h_B$.

Then conclude that the distance between $B$ and $A$ is less than $h_B$, the distance between $B$ and $L$ is less than $h_B$, so the distance between $B$ and $A$ is less than 2 times $h_B$, hence we have $h_A \leq 2*h_B$.

I feel this is making the implicit assumption that a tree rooted at $B$ will also have node $L$ as the farthest node, and I don't think I understand why this has to be the case (intuitively).

Comment: As stated below, you can always travel from $L$ to $A$ to $B$.  Each leg of this path has length at most $h_A$, so the whole path must have length at most $2h_A$.

Comment: @RobertShore So if the tree rooted at $B$ has the farthest node $L_2$ in the tree, $L_2$ plays no role whatsoever in this problem?

Comment: Correct.  You can get from any other node in the tree to $B$ by traveling through $A$, and each leg of that path can have length no more than $h_A$ because $h_A$ is defined as the maximum length from $A$ to any other node.  That's what the answer of @MishaLavrov is saying.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks. I need to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @RobertShore So instead of using $d(B, L)$ and $d(B, A)$, would two arbitrary edge of length 1 from $B$ (assuming it has at least two edges) also work, since they are surely $\leq h_B$? I'm assuming the answer is no, because $d(L, A)$ could be 1?

Comment: The answer is no because in order to get a bound on $h_B$ (which is what you're looking for) you need a bound on the length of a path from $B$ to an arbitrary point in the tree.  You don't get to limit yourself to the points adjacent to $B$.  You need a bound that works for all points in the tree.

Comment: I'll note, by the way, that I stated the solution incorrectly.  I should have said that you can get from any arbitrary point $L$ to $A$ by first going through $B$, and that path gives you the bound you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are not assuming that.

We have $d(A,L) = h_A$ by definition: we picked $L$ to be as far as possible from $A$.

We have inequalities $d(B,A) \le h_B$ and $d(B,L) \le h_B$ because $h_B$ is the maximum possible distance from $B$, and $d(B,A), d(B,L)$ are distances from $B$. Even if $A$ or $L$ happen to be much close to $B$ than that, the inequality still holds.

Because $d(A,L) \le d(A,B) + d(B,L)$ from the triangle inequality, we get $h_A \le h_B + h_B$.